# TypeScript compiler doesn't recognize exported class

Tags: typescript

I have following modules in my app:

In Loader.ts:

```
module Loader {

    export default class FLoader {

        constructor () {}

        // blahblahblah...

    }
}
```

In Renderer.ts:

```
import Loader from "../Loader";

module Renderer {

    export default class FRenderer {

        constructor () {}

        public SomeFunction(): void {

            let myLoader = new Loader(); // error: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature

        }

    }
}
```

And I get error noted in the code: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature

I'm following the docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to instantiate `Loader` which is a module instead of `FLoader` which is a class. A module can't not be instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it should be:

```
export module Loader {
    export class FLoader {
        constructor () {}

        // blahblahblah...
    }
}
```

And then:

```
import * as Loader from "./Loader";

let myLoader = new Loader.FLoader();
```

At least that works for me.

---

#### Edit

As @JimW commented, this code won't work, it should be used like this:

```
let myLoader = new Loader.Loader.FLoader();
```

To make it work it should be:

```
// Loader.ts
export class FLoader {
    constructor () {}

    // blahblahblah...
}
```

And then importing it:

```
import * as Loader from "./Loader";
let myLoader = new Loader.FLoader();
```

There's no need to create a `module` for `Loader`, as it happens already just by using a different file for it.

Comment: Any idea why in Visual Studio Code I have to do `let myLoader = new Loader.Loader.FLoader();` when using your example?

Comment: @JimW Right, check my revised answer

Comment: Thanks, I get it now the `as XXXX` in the import is the namespace/module name that it is imported as.